# Campo buscar do DataTable não funciona em uma única listagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Tenho o seguinte **dataTable**:

```
var tabela = table.DataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    language : {
      emptyTable:     "Nenhum registro encontrado",
      info:           "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registro(s)",
      infoEmpty:      "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registro(s)",
      infoFiltered:   "(filtrado de _MAX_ regitros no total)",
      infoPostFix:    "",
      thousands:      ",",
      lengthMenu:     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
      loadingRecords: "Carregando...",
      processing:     "Processando...",
      search:         "Buscar:",
      zeroRecords:    "Nenhum registro correspondente encontrado",
      paginate: {
          first:      "Primeiro",
          last:       "Último",
          next:       "Próximo",
          previous:   "Anterior"
      },
      aria: {
          sortAscending :  ": activate to sort column ascending",
          sortDescending : ": activate to sort column descending"
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [
      {orderable: false, targets: -1}
    ]
  });    

  $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var collumns_str = $(this).attr('data-columns')
    var collumns = collumns_str.split(",")
    collumns.forEach(function(collumn) {
      var column = tabela.column( collumn );  
      column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    })
  });  
  
});
```

Os dados que alimentam o **dataTable** chegam todos de uma vez em uma só *consulta* ao **banco** trazida no **controller** e entregue à **view**.

```
...    
    $dados['dados'] = $this->$model->listar();

    $this->load->vars($dados);
    $this->_admin('view_'.$this->router->class.'_listar');
  }
```

E é apresentado corretamente na **tela**.

Mas,... embora tenha os **lançamentos** corretos aparecendo, não consigo **buscar** nada no campo **Buscar**!

O que estará errado?

Por exemplo, lá tem na **coluna** **nome** : **José Geraldo**, então quando coloco no busca a letra **J,** já limpa o **dataTable** e diz não ter retorno

Obs.: uso esse mesmo **arquivo** **JS** em outras **listagens** e nelas a **busca** funciona corretamente.

Comment: Descobri o problema: Ao invés dos lançamentos estarem sendo lançados no DataTable como texto plano estavam como campos de formulário, então não funciona a busca. Gostaria de saber se um moderador o que fazer nesse caso? Fecho a pergunta ou posto como resposta?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Minha solução é basicamente uma verificação de uma **class**

```
$(function(){
  
  // Datatables
  $('.dataTables').each(function() {

$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-input'] = function(value) {
    return $(value).val();
};

if($(".rec_hum").length)
  collunms_def =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] 
//else if($(".outra_div").length)
//  collunms_def =  [1, 2, 3,... suas colunas] 
else 
  collunms_def =  [] 

var table = $(this);

var tabela = table.DataTable({
      autoWidth: false,
      language : {
        emptyTable:     "Nenhum registro encontrado",
        info:           "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registro(s)",
        infoEmpty:      "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registro(s)",
        infoFiltered:   "(filtrado de _MAX_ regitros no total)",
        infoPostFix:    "",
        thousands:      ",",
        lengthMenu:     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        loadingRecords: "Carregando...",
        processing:     "Processando...",
        search:         "Buscar:",
        zeroRecords:    "Nenhum registro correspondente encontrado",
        paginate: {
            first:      "Primeiro",
            last:       "Último",
            next:       "Próximo",
            previous:   "Anterior"
        },
        aria: {
            sortAscending :  ": activate to sort column ascending",
            sortDescending : ": activate to sort column descending"
        }
      },
      columnDefs: [{ 
          ordenable: true,
          type: "html-input", 
          targets: collunms_def
      }] 
    });    
............
```

Adicionei

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-input'] = function(value) {
    return $(value).val();
};
```

para pegar também os **inouts**

e,

```
var collunms_def = $(".rec_hum").length ? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] : [];
```

Na listagem/formulário, acrescentei uma **class**  rec_hum e verifiquei se ela é existente, se sim, informei um conjunto de colunas a serem buscadas nelas pelos valores do campo de busca

Fica ai para o caso de alguém precisar

No caso de ter mais **forms/listas** com campos de formulário, basta fazer um switch case e filtrar qual a **class** que está chegando e informar quais **colunas** serão pesquisadas

Comment: Me negativaram SOMENTE após eu adicionar a resposta , ninguém OUSOU A POSTAR UMA RESPOSTA. Dúvida: É ou não perseguição? Se querem aparecer, coloque uma resposta melhor do que a que eu coloquei depois de vários dias de esforços de pesquisa. Ai soim, vou te respeitar!

Comment: kkkk, é uma turma de ... mesmo! Não em como respeitar vocês